# Duplicit requests in GKE NEG (container-native load balancing)

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, gke-networking

I am using container-native load balancing (NEG on GKE) and I would like to ask, if is there is any option that same single request to load balancer can be processed twice (or more times) - by giving to more pods.

I have this suspicion, that is happening only because of NEG (there is no way to send more requests from my App) and according to logged time I found 3x same timestamp (seconds) of this LB request (this log is collected from all pods of course).

k8s final configs: https://gist.github.com/Barbarossa-42/86aac72da68c9e95a726e0845334d68a

UPDATE: its happening when LB timeout is reached or when pod crashed. For me there is a strange behaviour. Why its sending this request again to another (working) pod?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Do you have this issue constantly? Please update your question with configuration files. Do you use Pod Readiness feedback or hardcoded delay?

Comment: I've checked test application described at https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/container-native-load-balancing on my cluster and found no issues.

Comment: @SerhiiRohoza i am using Readiness f. I think its happening when some request taking too much time (goes to timeout) and LB gives same request to different pod (or something) while previous pod is still working or already processed all his  work (if sigterm was send)...

Comment: Please update your question with your configuration files. It's hard to proceed any further right now.

Comment: @SerhiiRohoza updated. Thanks for help.

Comment: What king of logging system do you use? Can you check logs directly on your pods https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#interacting-with-running-pods and compare them to logs at the logging system?